# why recursive factorial is faster than fold in ceylon

Tags: performance, ceylon

I have this ceylon code :

```
Integer fact(Integer n)
{
    return (n<=1)then 1 else n*fact(n-1);
}
Integer? factorial(Integer|String|Null n)
{
    Integer? num;
    if(is String n)
    {
        num=parseInteger(n);
    }
    else if(is Integer n)
    {
        num=n;      
    }   
    else
    {
        num=null;
    }
    if(exists num)
    {
        if(num<0)
        {
            return null;
        }
        if(num==0)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        return (2..num).fold(1)((x,y)=>x*y);//line 1
    }
    else
    {
        return null;        
    }       
}
shared void main() 
{
    print("enter a number");
    value input=process.readLine()?.trimmed;
    value starttime=system.milliseconds;
    value fact=factorial(input);
    value elapsedtime=(system.milliseconds-starttime).float/1000;
    if(exists fact)
    {
        print("(!n)=``fact``");
        print(elapsedtime);
    }
    else
    {
        print("Error, either you gave a negative number or you didn't enter an integer(or did you left the input blank ?)");
    }   
}
```

On line 1 I'm using fold to calculate the factorial, I get performance between 0.08 and 0.06 seconds.

Now if I replace line 1 with this :

```
return fact(num);
```

I get performance between 0.021 and 0.012, why is that ?

The number I tried was 10 in this case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

a couple of remarks first:

- don't use `system.milliseconds` for small measurements, it's notoriously imprecise (it's max resolution is 1/60th of a second or about 16ms), use `system.nanoTime` instead
- for the Java VM this is too small of a benchmark to be able to say anything worthwhile, the VM needs to "warm up" before it does any optimizations. See [How do I write a correct micro-benchmark in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java) for more information

But besides that one reason the `fact()` might be faster is because its code gets optimized internally to use Java primitive types while the `fold()` is a generic function which might mean that a lot of boxing is taking place.

Right now Ceylon is not so good yet at optimizing functions having generic parameters or return types when dealing with basic types like `Integer` and `Float` and such. Hopefully in a future version we'll be able to remedy that somewhat.